# Tracker capture android app for DHIS2.20 is not working

Tags: dhis2

We are trying to use the app with our DHIS2 2.20 server. The app logs in and seems to be loading the data but eventually no org. units show up in the list.

Is any additional setup required for the app to work in terms of database or tomcat server configuration?

Comment: whom can we contact for support/queries on the android app?

Comment: Probably not the right place for this question.

Comment: best is that you subscribe to the DHIS 2 Dev list and ask for support there. More details can be found here: https://www.dhis2.org/contact

Answer (score -1):

For organisation units and programs to show up in the app they need to be assigned directly to the user. 
That means that for each organisation unit you want to have available on the Android app you will need to assign the user directly. If you for example are a super user assigned to the top level org unit, it would not be enough, and you'd have to assign the user to other org units as well.

To verify that you have assigned correctly, you can check the api endpoint /me/programs (i.e. https://play.dhis2.org/demo/api/me/programs) and verify that the organisation units object has org units with programs (see example from play.dhis2.org/demo below).

```
organisationUnits": {

    "DiszpKrYNg8": 
    {
        "id": "DiszpKrYNg8",
        "label": "Ngelehun CHC",
        "level": ​4,
        "parent": "YuQRtpLP10I",
        "programs": [
            {
                "id": "fDd25txQckK",
                "label": "Provider Follow-up and Support Tool"
            },
            {
                "id": "eBAyeGv0exc",
                "label": "Inpatient morbidity and mortality"
            },
            {
                "id": "uy2gU8kT1jF",
                "label": "MNCH / PNC (Adult Woman)"
            },
            {
                "id": "q04UBOqq3rp",
                "label": "Information Campaign"
            },
            {
                "id": "ur1Edk5Oe2n",
                "label": "TB program"
            },
            {
                "id": "IpHINAT79UW",
                "label": "Child Programme"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```